# How to Compare multiple cells with two possible values in one row in google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

After googling for days, i couldn't come up to the correct query/formular.  can someone please help me with this ?

[image: Input]

I would like to get out the table above the three results :

[image: Desired output]

Thank you so much .

ps: sorry for the pictures, i could't past part of the sheet here

Comment: Share the formulas you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

A simple approach is to use `COUNTIFS` to count the number of occurrences of `F` and `M` in your data set, then use `IF` and `IFS` to build the summaries you need.

Start by setting up a set of cells like this:

[image]

You don't have to do it this way, but it's a lot easier. You'll see why in a moment.

First, let's use `COUNTIFS` to count the number of male cats. Assuming that your data lives in cells `B1:J2` and that the cells shown above live in cells `B4:D9`, you'd use the following formula:

`=COUNTIFS($B$1:$J$1 , B$4 & "*", $B$2:$J$2, $A5)`

Read up on `COUNTIFS` to get a general sense of what's going on.

The `$` in the cell references force the references to stay the same when you paste or drag them, which is handy because now you can just drag the formula right to get counts for dogs and birds. If you then select the M/cats/dogs/birds cells, you can drag them down to get the `F` counts easily as well.

Now it's just a case of using `IF`, `IFS` and `MAX` to summarize your results. Here are some examples for the cats column.

**biggest gender**: `=IFS(B5 > B6, "M", B5 < B6, "F", B5 = B6, "-")`

**biggest gender count**: `=IF(B5 = B6, "", MAX(B5:B6))`

**gender > 2**: `=IF(N(B8) > 2, "good", "bad")`

Note the use of `N` above to force the cell values to be numeric. Without this, you'll get unexpected results when comparing numbers to strings.

Good luck!

Comment: thank you for taking you're time to explain, very informative.  Great idea to change the table structure. i will take that in consideration. thank you again.

Comment: No worries and happy spreadsheeting! If the answer works for you, do you want to accept the answer?